# Should Node.js/Express Routers Be Wrapped in a Class When Using TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, typescript

I am using `Node.js/Express` and using `TypeScript` and wondering if `router` files should be encapsulated as a class?

It seems kind of pointless to me for middleware and router is just a variable.

Should I be doing this to follow Object-Oriented design principles when using TypeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I be doing this to follow Object-Oriented design principles when using TypeScript

No. Use what makes sense to you. Nothing wrong with functions if they make sense.

In fact the TypeScript compiler source *doesn't have a single usage of the `class` keyword*.

Comment: Thanks basarat. Does it even make sense to do so if one were so inclined? I didn't think so but this is for a university project and we are cart blanche being told to put everything into classes. I couldn't really get a good explanation out of anyone except for "just do it to make it more OO".

Comment: I'm not sure why you would. Forced OO isn't any better than cowboy coding. Follow the design patterns set out by the creators of the package. Or, follow the design patterns set out by Microsoft in [their own typescript examples](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScriptSamples/blob/master/imageboard/app.ts)

Comment: @AdamThompson for a university example where using a class is a *requirement* you can *force* yourself to do this. Sorry about that, but no need in the real world for this library.